# Receive Server Sent Events (SSE) in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, server-sent-events

I have an ASP.net core 3.1 server project that has a very simple API sending one-way Server Sent Events (SSE) like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task Get()
{
    var response = Response;
    response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
    response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");

    for (var i = 0; true; ++i)
    {
        await response.WriteAsync($"id: unique{i}\n");
        await response.WriteAsync("event: add\n");
        //await response.WriteAsync("retry: 10000\n");
        await response.WriteAsync($"data: Controller {i} at {DateTime.Now}\n\n");

        response.Body.Flush();
        await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Now I want to receive these events via C# UWP Client. Unfortunately I only receive the first event:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/subscription"))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I create a behavior in UWP in order to always listen to that connection and receiving events that I can process further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution here https://techblog.dorogin.com/server-sent-event-aspnet-core-a42dc9b9ffa9.
The trick was to not set up a WebAPI-call that continuously returns data like in the question but to create a data-strem with the MIME-type `text/event-stream`.

On the UWP client side you then read the stream like this:

```
var stream = httpClient.GetStreamAsync(requestUri).Result;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how you would do this if your endpoint requires a HttpPost instead of HttpGet?

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient` begins by initiating a request and ends when it receives the data returned by the server.

This is equivalent to making only one request. If you want to build a continuous data transmission channel between the application and the server, try using [WebSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/websockets)

Here is a code example using WebSocket for reference: [WebSocket sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebSocket)

---

In addition, when debugging with Visual Studio, you can access localhost, but when publishing the application, UWP will not be able to access localhost due to the [local network loopback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback)

Thanks.

Comment: I tried `WebSocket` from the WebSocket sample link and I get an `ArgumentException` saying the WebSocket-URIs must match the schema "ws://" or "wss://", which is obviously doesn't, as I did not implement a WebSocket on the server-side (which I do not want to do).

Comment: For common TCP requests, the request is initiated by the client, and the server accepts the request and responds. Judging from the description of your problem, you want the server to continuously return data, which requires a two-way channel between the server and the client. `WebSocket` is a solution, but this requires adjustment by the server. If you don’t want to adjust the code of the server, you can consider adding a timer (like `DispatcherTimer`) to the client to request content regularly, but this is not a recommended method.

Comment: In most cases you would be right, but I really mean client-side subscription to SSE as one-way instead of WebSocket (as explained here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/sse-websockets-data-flow-http2/). I found my solution here: https://techblog.dorogin.com/server-sent-event-aspnet-core-a42dc9b9ffa9

Comment: Glad you solved the problem, this is a very useful solution. You can write your solution and mark it as the answer, this will help more people who have the same problem.